# Possible to use R.__ with semver functions?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, semantic-versioning

```js
const semvers = ["5.100.0-rc.0", "5.97.3", "5.97.1"];
const newRecord = "5.97.2";
```

Given the above test data, I wish to insert `newRecord` into the right order, defined/sorted by semver package.

```js
result = ["5.100.0-rc.0", "5.97.3", "5.97.2", "5.97.1"];
```

Below is my attempt which gave me the correct result

```js
const semvers = ["5.100.0-rc.0", "5.97.3", "5.97.1"];
const newRecord = "5.97.2";

const indexResult = R.findIndex(x => semver.lt(x, newRecord))(semvers);
const result = R.insert(indexResult, newRecord, semvers)
```

Then, i was wondering if I can replace `x` with `R.__`, so i attempted below

```js
const indexResult = R.findIndex(semver.lt(R.__, newRecord))(semvers);
```

I had the impression that `R.__` referring to the arguments that was gonna passed but seems like it's not, or it was simply due to the fact that `semver.lt` is not a curried function and hence couldn't comprehend `R.__`?

Answer (score 2):

`R.__` works with Ramda functions or functions curried with Ramda e.g.,

```
const semvers = ["5.100.0-rc.0", "5.97.3", "5.97.1"];
const newRecord = "5.97.2";

const findVer = R.curryN(2, semver.lt)(R.__, newRecord);

const indexResult = R.findIndex(findVer, semvers);
const result = R.insert(indexResult, newRecord, semvers);
```

My preferred option would have been: `R.flip(semver.lt)(newRecord)` unfortunately `semver.lt` [arity is 3](https://github.com/npm/node-semver/blob/main/functions/lt.js#L2) (third argument is a `loose` parameter) so `R.flip` doesn't work straight out of the box.

With `R.partialRight` you could supply the last two arguments (including that undocumented (?) `loose` parameter):

```
const findVer = R.partialRight(semver.lt, [newRecord, false]);
```

But honestly what you had originally is fine.